# Install latest version of dotnet-sdk by script

Tags: apt, bash, 18.10, dotnet

I am writing an installer script and need to install dotnet-sdk.
I want to install the latest version which is 3.1 or in future 3.2 or whatever.
Now I found that there are 2 versions in apt-get:

```bsh
user@NUC7CJYH:~$ apt search dotnet-sdk-3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
dotnet-sdk-3.0/now 3.0.103-1 amd64 [installed,local]
  Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.0.103

dotnet-sdk-3.1/focal 3.1.301-1 amd64
  Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.301
```

Then I store the results in an array:

```
user@NUC7CJYH:~$ d=($(apt search dotnet-sdk-3 2>/dev/null | grep dotnet | cut -c 1-14))&&echo ${d[@]}
dotnet-sdk-3.0 dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Now I got stuck in sorting the array by version and getting the index for the latest version.

I am wondering if this is the right way (sorting the array, get the string and apt install this version) or if someone knows a command that automatically installs the latest release?

Best regards, Stefan

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but that's also your problem. Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Your tested & supported *release-upgrade* path is now also gone, as 18.10 upgraded to 19 04 which now too is EOL. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: I am aware this issue but in this case this doesn't make the different. In production Ubuntu 20LTS will be used but the dev PCs are on 18...

Comment: You could loop through the results once comparing the major and minor versions to find the highest one available without worrying about their index. Just default to the first item and loop through, only replacing when major is higher or major is equal and minor is higher. You may want to filter out the possibly-incompatible version(s) though, i.e. /focal, as you're on a lesser OS version.

Answer (score 0):

To keep packages upto date I would expect `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` should suffice.   I use python to find the highest version number returned by a command

```
import re, sys
from distutils.version import StrictVersion

def get_release(out):
    r = re.compile(f'.*([v]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$')
    maxrel = "0.0.0"
    for rel in out:
        if r.match(rel) is not None:
            rel= r.split(rel)[1]
            if StrictVersion(rel) > StrictVersion(maxrel): maxrel = rel

    return maxrel

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_release(sys.stdin.read().split("\n")))
```

the command you have noted doesn't return same results for me.  I pasted text to a file

```
$ cat dotnet.txt | python3 maxver.py 
3.1.301
```

getting highest available version from git:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --refs https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git | python3 maxver.py
3.5.1
```

putting it together to download latest version

```
$ wget -nv https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/$(git ls-remote --tags --refs https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git | python3 maxver.py).zip
2020-06-16 10:49:01 URL:https://codeload.github.com/jquery/jquery/zip/3.5.1 [1520729/1520729] -> "3.5.1.zip" [1]
```

Comment: Hi Rob,
I can install dotnet 3.0 or 3.1 and keep both actual - this is the reason why apt upgrade won't work. And how by script will I determine which one to install? 
Writing a Py script is _one_ way to do what I want. As Bash will definitively be able to do what I want I don't want all the overhead with a py interpreter and the script.

Comment: Hi - I was following the fact you said you wanted the latest version.  I've done a lot of bash over the years and get the point keep to one scripting solution.  IMHO finding highest version number contained in stdout from another command is best parsed in something like python. Clearly approach I used to parse can be done in bash but is less readable / maintainable

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it like this:

```bsh
desc="install dotnet SDK"
# find latest dotnet release (in version tree 3.x)
dotnet_releases=($(apt search dotnet-sdk-3 2>/dev/null | grep dotnet | cut -c 1-14))
dotnet_sorted=($(printf '%s\n' "${dotnet_releases[@]}" | sort -r))
echo -e  "Latest dotnet version in the 3.x branch is: ${dotnet_sorted[0]} "

dpkg -s ${dotnet_sorted[0]}
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    apt-get install -q -y "${dotnet_sorted[0]}" && success $desc || failed $desc
else 
    success $desc
fi
```

Please ignore my success or failed functions, they just echo strings and do some logging.